# (Teamviewer) My school laptop brightness is broken

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card, teamviewer, brightness

I installed Teamviewer monitor driver and the brightness settings werent changing the screen brightnesss its stuck at 100%. So I updated the display adapter and replaced intel hd graphics 4000 with intel hd graphics. now the setting for brightness is gone.

ive tried uninstalling the driver for teamspeak before but got "A problem occured during uninstallation. the TeamViewer monitor driver was NOT uninstalled successfully from your system."

The screen brightness is chewing up the battery life and is hurting my eyes.

Windows 10, Acer Netbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://kzhiwei.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-laptop-screen-brightness-slider-windows-7

The solution was to go to Device manager, uninstall the monitor (and check remove driver as well).